# Can you add markup to table cells created using angular ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am considering using ng-grid for a new angular application.  The grid that we are creating requires html markup in each individual cell.

A very simplified example is in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cv5HM2SdK2X60GS2yvhG?p=preview). The ui-grid widget has some cells that want to use the `<strong>` and `<em>` tags. However, the markup is displayed as a string, not as DOM.

So, this is what I have:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="mygrid">
  <div ng-controller="GridCtrl">
    <div ui-grid="{ data: myData }"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('mygrid', ['ui.grid'])
  .controller('GridCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Andrew';
    $scope.data = [{
      first: '<em>Andrew</em>',
      last: '<strong>Eisenberg</strong>'
    }];
  });
```

I would like this to be displayed as DOM, instead of text. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have control over your data (i.e. you can change your data from:

```
$scope.data = [{
  first: '<em>Andrew</em>',
  last: '<strong>Eisenberg</strong>'
}];
```

to:

```
$scope.data = [{
  first: 'Andrew',
  last: 'Eisenberg'
}];
```

you can define `columnDefs` with `cellTemplates` (that contain the HTML template) as follows:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
   columnDefs: [
     { 
       field: 'first',
       cellTemplate: '<em>{{COL_FIELD}}</em>'
     },
     { 
       field: 'last',
       cellTemplate: '<strong>{{COL_FIELD}}</strong>'
     },
   ],
```

See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VureIdUZgjLCKqypNzWn?p=preview) for an example when using ui-grid. If you happen to be using an ng-grid you can do something similar, but instead of `COL_FIELD` use `row.getProperty(col.field)`. See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/M45E5h1Tua1IEbd6jPjv?p=preview) for an ng-grid example.

**Edit: If you have no control over the data and it must contain HTML**

If you haven't got control of your data (i.e. your data must contain the markup) e.g:

```
$scope.data = [{
  first: '<em>Andrew</em>',
  last: '<strong>Eisenberg</strong>'
}];
```

then you can do as follows. Create a cell template that can render HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="emailTemplate">
    <div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-bind-html="COL_FIELD"></span></div>
</script>
```

Define `columnDefs` that reference the template as follows:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    { 
      field: 'first',
      cellTemplate: 'htmlTemplate'
    },
    { 
      field: 'last',
      cellTemplate: 'htmlTemplate'
    },
  ],
```

Note: You'll need to include the [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) library to render and sanitize the HTML:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.grid']);
```

See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WSd23ph8Pk5RVP0u1Yfw?p=preview) for a demo.

Comment: This is great. I do have complete control over the data. I was including html in the strings just to show what I wanted to do, but failed. It looks like this will work. I've decided to go with another option, though. https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table